# Limiting Hive 1.2.1. (HDInsight 3.6) to running only SELECT queries

Tags: hive, azure-hdinsight

I have the following version stack that I am using to run Hive:-

- HDInsight 3.6
- Hadoop 2.7
- Hive 1.2.1

Is there any way I can create an HDInsight cluster against the same Hive Metastore but it will only allow SELECT queries and nothing else (no insert/overwrite/drop , no alter table commands etc). All the other clusters using that shared metastore should continue to have regular access.

Comment: In order to test the scenario, Could you please share more details on how exactly you are running the hive queries (Share sample queries which you have tried and which are not working). Have you created HDInsight cluster with Hive metastore?

Comment: there is nothing that is not working -- rather I am saying is that I need an interface or a query cluster against shared Hive metastore so that it will not allow any query that modifies metastore data -- such as alter table , drop table/view , create table/view , alter table , create database, create view etc. It should only only SELECT queries srrictly. The way we run our production pipeline queries is through ADFv2 (Hive activities). But then we also have business users querying through other clusters which point to the same shared metastore.We want to restrict these users to only run SELECT

Answer (score 0):

There is no such specific utility/interface to achieve that. If I understand your concern correctly, your Metastore is shared between clusters and you want to have only `select` query access for a specific cluster. If your tables are not scattered or it's inside a specific database then this should work smoothly. Did you check on the access part providing only view access to all the users which will prohibit them to alter or run DML statements? Have a look at this link-[https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_security/content/user_access_hive_db_tables_cmd_line.html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/domain-joined/apache-domain-joined-run-hive#create-ranger-policies)  You can also make use of Apache Ranger if yours is an ESP cluster-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/domain-joined/apache-domain-joined-run-hive#create-ranger-policies

[image]

**Note**: I didn't focus on the specific versions, you can test it out

Hope this helps

Comment: You can accept it if it was helpful for you. This will also help other community members